# Formulário php redirecionando pra e-mail

Tags: php, html, css

Alguém pode me ajudar com um erro que estou tendo com um formulário ....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>enviando E-Mail</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $nome=$_POST['nome'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $assunto=$_POST['assunto'];
        $mensagem=$_POST['mensagem'];   
        ?>  
        <?php 

            $to = "carcasa2013@gmail.com";
            $subject = "$assunto";
            $message = "<strong>Nome:</strong> $nome<br /><br /><strong>E-Mail:</strong> $email<br /><br /><strong>Assunto:</strong> $assunto<br /><br /><strong>Mensagem</strong> $mensagem<br /><br />";
            $header = "MINE-Version: 1.0\n";
            $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
            $header .= "From: $email\n";
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
            echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Quando aperta no Botão enviar da a msg do acho mensagem enviada com sucesso mais não envia o email :( o que pode ser ?

Comment: coloca um `var_dump(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header));` pra ver se da erro

Comment: Deu isso bool(false) Mensagem enviada com sucesso

Comment: Seu código só tem um problema, aliás 2 problemas, primeiro    $subject = "$assunto";` deve ser `$subject = $assunto;`. segundo usar gmail, esse treco, estou cansado de ver que dá problemas. Testei seu código do jeito que está no meu servidor e funcionou perfeitamente. O problema é no gmail que não roda qualquer script. de email, acho que deve ser configurado de acordo com o que eles estipulam, e isso eu não sei como é.

Comment: Botei no servidor    $subject = $assunto;    e troquei o email pro hotmail. Ainda não chega nem na lixeira nem na principal

Comment: N consegui ;(  n da certo

Comment: Está executando em ambiente local ou hospedagem?

Comment: Usando hospedagem ... kinghost precisa habilitar algo ?

Comment: I ela é uma plataforma Linux!